# $('.myclass') ONLY when under this id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have 2 div ids `#dfirst` and `#dfirst` each has elements of class `.clickme`. I want to select the `.clickme` that are under only `#dfirst` but not the ones under `#dsecond`. **Note that the level of nesting is somewhat unpredictable and may be different from what I've got here, so I'm looking for something that's flexible in terms of nesting**. So jquery gurus, can it be done?

```
<div id="dfirst">
  <div>
   <div> 
     <div class="clickme" ></div>
     <div class="clickme" ></div>
     <div class="clickme" ></div>
   <div>
  <div/>

</div>

<div id="dsecond">
   <div> 
     <div>
       <div>
          <div>
            <div class="clickme" ></div>
            <div class="clickme" ></div>
            <div class="clickme" ></div>
          <div>
       <div>
     <div>
</div>
```

Comment: well as you have it now nothing will work your syntaxt is wrong you dont close like this  `<div/> or  <div>`

Comment: @Breezer, typo here. I got it right in my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a space (the [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)), like this:

```
$("#dfirst .clickme")
```

It'll find `.clickme` elements at any level beneath `#dfirst`, the same as `$("#dfirst").find(".clickme")` would.

Comment: I'm sure I tried this before posting, but it didn't work. Let me try again.

Comment: @silow - make sure you're running it in a `document.ready` handler, so the elements are in the DOM to find.

Answer (score 2):

A space character means "descendant", it doesn't matter how many levels of nesting as long as `.clickme` is *inside* `#dfirst`.

```
$('#dfirst .clickme')
```

This is different from the following, which means only `.clickme` that is found directly within `#dfirst`.

```
$('#dfirst > .clickme')
```

Answer (score 1):

`$("#first .clickme")` will serves you.

The JQuery's Selector CheatSheet is a must have reference for any web developer using it.

Here is a version by [DZone](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/jquery-selectors)